# Getting error while deploying rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I m getting this error while deploying my app from github on heroku ...

build log -->

```
-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

       Installing i18n 0.7.0

       Installing rake 10.5.0

       Installing minitest 5.8.3

       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5

       Installing builder 3.2.2

       Installing erubis 2.7.0

       Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0

       Installing rack 1.6.4

       Installing mime-types 2.99

       Installing sass 3.4.21

       Installing thor 0.19.1

       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0

       Installing formtastic_i18n 0.6.0

       Using bundler 1.11.2

       Installing arel 6.0.3

       Installing execjs 2.6.0

       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0

       Installing tilt 1.4.1

       Installing bcrypt 3.1.7 with native extensions

       Installing cancan 1.6.10

       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0

       Installing multi_json 1.11.2

       Installing request_store 1.3.0

       Installing puma 2.16.0 with native extensions

       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4

       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4

       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2

       Installing rack-test 0.6.3

       Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1 with native extensions

       Installing warden 1.2.6

       Installing rdoc 4.2.1

       Installing mail 2.6.3

       Installing bourbon 4.2.7

       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1

       Installing uglifier 2.5.3

       Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.3.1

       Installing sprockets 3.5.2

       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2

       Installing sdoc 0.4.0

       Installing activesupport 4.2.2

       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.6

       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3

       Installing globalid 0.3.6

       Installing arbre 1.0.3

       Installing activemodel 4.2.2

       Installing jbuilder 2.2.3

       Installing pundit 1.1.0

       Installing activejob 4.2.2

       Installing activerecord 4.2.2

       Installing polyamorous 1.3.0

       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7

       Installing loofah 2.0.3

       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2

       Installing actionview 4.2.2

       Installing actionpack 4.2.2

       Installing actionmailer 4.2.2

       Installing railties 4.2.2

       Installing formtastic 3.1.4

       Installing has_scope 0.6.0

       Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0

       Installing kaminari 0.16.3

       Installing ransack 1.7.0

       Installing draper 2.1.0

       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0

       Installing responders 2.1.1

       Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5

       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3

       Installing rails 4.2.2

       Installing turbolinks 2.3.0

       Installing sass-rails 5.0.2

       Installing inherited_resources 1.6.0

       Installing devise 3.5.6

       Installing activeadmin 1.0.0.pre2

       Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

       Post-install message from rdoc:

       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported

       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install

       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install

       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!

       Bundle completed (23.34s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

 !

 !     Could not detect rake tasks

 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app

 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.

 !     rake aborted!

 !     Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'activeadmin'.

 !     /tmp/build_e5688395917c72f2956d14c05dd2fdf5/nischaynamdev-hostel_mess_pay-a993b86d6645abbdfb41cb6de99c6900648d588f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'

 !     /tmp/build_e5688395917c72f2956d14c05dd2fdf5/nischaynamdev-hostel_mess_pay-a993b86d6645abbdfb41cb6de99c6900648d588f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'

 !     /tmp/build_e5688395917c72f2956d14c05dd2fdf5/nischaynamdev-hostel_mess_pay-a993b86d6645abbdfb41cb6de99c6900648d588f/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11
```

My production.rb file :

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.force_ssl = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile =true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.assets.precompile +=
      %w( #{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)
  config.assets.precompile +=
      %w( #{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee)

  RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'messpay.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port           => '587',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => 'heroku.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
end
```

**rakefile**

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

GEMFILE:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'

  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.7'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma', '~> 2.16'
end
```

I have tried most of precompiled command options you can check my production.rb but build logs are showing problem in active admin gem !

help me plz thxx

Comment: i'd try connecting to the heroku machine with `heroku run bash` and try installing the activeadmin gem manually. You might see more useful errors that way.

Comment: getting this error !

Comment: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)`
@maxpleaner

Comment: It's usually a good thin when you get a different error. A lot of time gems have external dependencies. Please post the full error trace for this DependencyError *in your question**

Comment: ok I am adding .. just wait

Comment: [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/KHT4V9rA) for build log @maxpleaner
And here is error log for  gem install activeadmin--->

Comment: I mean the `Gem::DependencyError`, which your build log doesn't include. Use `heroku run bash` then try  `gem install activeadmin` when you're connected.

Comment: ya Wait I m giving ...

Comment: [PasteBin Link for error log](http://pastebin.com/EemDeb3E) ! @maxpleaner

Comment: I have  pasted link above for  Gem::DependencyError

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your gem file. It appears to have an issue attempting to load the gem ActiveAdmin for the production environment, I would start there, possibly upload it to view.

**After reviewing the Gemfile... I think that may be ok.

So I'm thinking change `config.assets.compile =true` to `config.assets.compile = true` So basically add a space in case that is causing a problem. Then I would run `bundle exec rake -P` like it suggests in the error itself. And then try `rake assets:precompile` and see if that solves the problem. You probably will also need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` too. I had a problem like this before with Heroku myself.

Comment: do i need to put activeadmin gem on production group of gem file ?

Comment: Unsure without looking at the Gemfile itself.... I'm thinking that there's a fault in the production group setup. Can you edit the question to add the Gemfile contents?